# Running SQL Script file through Wix using <sql:SqlScript> element

Tags: sql-server, database, wix, installation

I am new to Wix Installer. I have a requirement where I have to provide credentials for SQL Server login and run a script from a specific path.

I am not getting what's going wrong.The project is build successfully and .msi is created. After running it I get the following Error:

**Error 26204. Error -2147217900: failed to execute SQL string, error detail: Incorrect syntax near '»'., SQL key: CreateUpsizingDatabase SQL string: ï»¿print convert(varchar(25),GetDate(),121) + ' Executing file: SqlTest.sql'**

My Sql Script File is as below:

print convert(varchar(25),GetDate(),121) + ' Executing file: SqlTest.sql'

**Below is My code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SqlTest" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="BLRSCCMCAS01" UpgradeCode="0931a445-07bf-4494-b130-a1f96155021f">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SqlTest" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>

    <Binary Id="CreateUpsizingDatabase" SourceFile="C:\Temp\SqlTest.sql" />

    <util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="[User]" Password="[Password]" />

    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="[MyDb]" Server="[Server]" User="SQLUser" />

    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SqlTest" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="SqlComponent" Guid="15CCE46E-8EA5-42CA-80C5-AC3DB30A9716">
        <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateDatabases" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateUpsizingDatabase" /> 
        <CreateFolder/>
      </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have a [UTF8 BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (ï»¿) in there. Try saving the file as "Unicode (UTF8 Without signature)" using the advanced save options in visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Man...You showed a well guided direction towards solving it..No Changes it the above code...Just if sql script file is created in Visual studio in my case VS12...it should be saved as with option encoding without signature..if file in sql file is created in SSMS dont need to do anything simple save...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, UTF8 with or without signature both failed.
I think the chars in our script string cause the problem (in my case, I included some chinese chars).

I tried to re-generated sql script from sql server, and save this file in **ANSI** format. It works!
And i did some query, the chinese chars are correct in sql server.

an article you might want to refer: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Error-executing-sql-scripts-with-WIX-td1488703.html